# Flutter or React Native - Better for web exports?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create a cross-platform app (will be supported for mobile and web devices), and right now I am not totally sure which technology to use. What is easest to make more responsive, flexible, and adaptive?

I have experience with RNative and Flutter, but I am not sure what to use, what is better for performance on mobile and web, SEO is not important. Only app size (if we talk about the mobile app) and performance (web app)?

Need suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8ipUgXH6jw

This will help you make right decision.